# Некорректное чтение строки из std::cin после чтения числового значения

Tags: c++, ввод

При считывании потока из командной строки в переменную с помощью `std::getline` не дает ввести данные, перескакивает. Как можно считать строку с пробелами в переменную избежав моей проблемы в `std::getline`

```
std::string  fio;
std::string  citi;
int id;

std::cout << "Введите id(число) абонента: ";
std::cin >> id;

std::cout << "Введите ФИО абонента: ";
std::getline(std::cin, fio, '\n');

std::cout <<"Введите город абонента: ";
std::cin >> citi;
```

ВЫВОД:
добавление абонента в группу пользователей

```
Введите id(число) абонента: 12
Введите ФИО абонента: Введите город абонента:
```

Answer (score 7):

Вставьте строку

```
#include <limits>

//...

std::cout << "Введите id(число) абонента: ";
std::cin >> id;

std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );

std::cout << "Введите ФИО абонента: ";
std::getline(std::cin, fio, '\n');
```

Проблема заключается в том, что в буфере ввода после использования оператора `operator >>` остается символ новой строки, соответствующий нажатой клавише Enter. А функция `std;:getline`  читает буфер, пока не встретится этот символ. Поэтому если его не удалить, то будет считана пустая строка.

Comment: Работает благодарю)

Answer (score 2):

Потому что после ввода числа в буфере остается символ `'\n'`. Он и считывается при вводе строки как пустая строка. Вам надо сбросить содержимое буфера перед вводом строки:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

При неверном вводе числа нужно еще сбросить флаг состояния ошибки `cin.clear()`.

Comment: Столкнулся с такой же проблемой как и автор вопроса. Попробовал Ваш вариант решения проблемы, но у меня max() помечается как ошибка: требуется идентификатор. Можете помочь это исправить?

Comment: Скорее всего, у вас макрос `max` из windows.h включен или еще откуда-то... Если windows.h включен - определите `#define NOMINMAX` перед ним. Ну ии, понятно, нужно включить `#include<limits>`.

Comment: спасибо, я уже решил эту проблему так как Вы и сказали

Answer (score 1):

```
(std::cin >> id).get();
```

Нужно проигнорировать символ переноса строки, потому что он остается и тогда getline читает пока не встретит этот символ и в итоге считывается пустая строка.

Comment: У меня на этом моменте проблема std::getline(std::cin, fio, '\n');