# Пропуск оператора

Tags: c++

Знающие, подскажите в чём ошибка. Задана такая задачка, надо реализовать интерфейс домашней аудио-коллекции, создал её так

```
struct Songs
{
    char name_autor[50];
    char name_song[50];
    double time;
};
class Audio_Collection
{
public:
    Songs audio[N];
    void set_audio();
    void print_audio();
    void sort_name_autor();
    void sort_name_song();
    void sort_time();
};
```

Вот реализация ф-ии ввода данных,

```
void Audio_Collection::set_audio()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите имя автора(группы): ";
        cin.getline(audio[i].name_autor, 50);
        cout << "Введите название песни: ";
        cin.getline(audio[i].name_song, 50);
        cout << "Введите продолжительность трека: ";
        cin >> audio[i].time;
    }
}
```

И вот в чём загвоздка, при вводе данных возникает такая ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При вводе второго последующих значений не выполняется строка

```
cin.getline(audio[i].name_autor, 50);
```

как это исправить?

Comment: @vp_arth Да его, заразу, каждый раз формулируют по-своему...Один бы раз в FAQ вынести какой...

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624723/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-stdcin-%D0%B2-stdstring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сбросьте буфер после чтения `double` - в нем же остается перевод строки... Добавьте после

```
cin >> audio[i].time;
```

строчку

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```